# Neo4j: Create various Nodes of type 1 and type 2 relate these 2 types of Nodes with 2 different relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, batch-processing

I'm using Neo4j to store data.

I have 2 types of data of GDP and Health. Each data has set of countries(say around 20) and set of years (say 1990-2013). Now I want to store each country as unique Node with label as country's name and each year as unique node with label as year. Countries and years are related(mapped) to one another by the above relationships of GDP,health.

I have already collected country names and years in 2 different SortedSet (java code).

I'm not sure if it will be best to add each country and year one-by-one as graphDB.createNode() as I think this will be too cumbersome to create and then define relationships or if it will be best to batchinsert all of these countries at one go and similarly batchinsert years at one time. But again when I have batch inserted all countries and years, how will I then define 2 relationships between them.

I would like if someone has a piece of java code or give advice on finding best solution for storage of data.

I must point that not all country has data for every year for any given relationship.

Thanks,
Hazel

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such a case to some extent..I had some nodes of different types

> x, y,z

and there was a relationship between x and it's corresponding y or z. I simply used the BatchInserter to insert all the nodes of all types, and after that I had some sql queries to get the relations between nodes, by finding the ids of nodes that must be connected.

So, I think you can insert all the nodes for both YEARS and COUNTRIES by looping through the tow sets you have, after that you may need a query or whatever else to get the relation between those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/) for a guide to importing data into Neo4j and [here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import) for additional tools (you can 'batch insert' both nodes and relationships, not sure what your hesitation is there).

I don't know what you mean by 'cumbersome'. If you use the batch tools above you can do first all nodes and then all relationships, but if you use the Java embedded API there is no need to do that. If you are concerned about duplicates, f.i. a case where you come upon a node first as a 'subject' as you iterate through your `SortedSet` and then again as an 'object' or end node of a relationship, you can take a look at [UniqueFactory](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create). It would allow you to build your graph in an order that is convenient given your data without worrying about creating duplicate nodes–just create each node, the remote nodes of its relationships, and the relationships between these. If the nodes already exist they will be updated, not duplicated. This is perhaps the most straightforward way, give it a try and ask again, a little more specifically, if you have trouble.